# Unable to delete S3 file showing "unexpected error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of objects in my bucket that are shown in the console as e.g:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET/foo%0A
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET/bar%0A

When I click on Overview and Properties, the console shows "An unexpected error occurred". When I click on one of these files I get a 404 saying it doesn't exist. **When I try to delete these files, the file isn't actually deleted.**

I don't know exactly how these files got into my bucket.

Any idea on how to delete these files?

Answer (score 1):

The strange characters are probably confusing the web-based management console.

You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to make API calls, such as:

```
aws s3 rm s3://MYBUCKET/foo*
aws s3 rm s3://MYBUCKET/bar*
```